# Proofs by Induction - Showing that a > b and b > c means a > c.

Tags: induction

I have a general question regarding induction, with an example provided. I'd also like any critique in my proof.

Suppose I'm trying to prove the following.

Define a sequence of integers a0, a1, a2, ... as follows:

$a_i$ = 2 if 0 $\le$ i $\le$ 2

$a_i$ = $a_{i-1}$ + $a_{i-2}$ + $a_{i-3}$ for i > 2

Prove that $a_n$ < $2^n$ for every integer n $\ge$ $2.$

I approach the proof as follows, using complete induction.

Base case:

1) Let i = 2, then $a_2$ = 2, and $2$ $\lt$ $2^2$ is true.

2) Let i = 3, then

$a_3$ = $a_{3-1}$ + $a_{3-2}$ + $a_{3-3}$

= 2 + 2 + 2

= 6 $\lt$ $2^3$ is true.

Induction Hypothesis: Suppose P(j) holds such that 2 $\le$ j < k. We need to show that p(k) holds, ie, $a_k$ $\lt$ $2^k$.

Induction Step:

$a_k$ = $a_{k-1}$ + $a_{k-2}$ + $a_{k-3}$

$\lt$ $2^{k-1}$ + $2^{k-2}$ + $2^{k-3}$ [By our induction hypothesis, k - 1, k - 2, and k-3 are all less than k and hold by IH.]

$\lt$ $2^k ({2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-3}})$ [Algebra]

$\lt$ $2^k$(${7/8}$)

$\lt$ $2^k(7/8)$ $\lt$ $2^k$ [This to me is trivially true, and where I would like critique on. Is there a better way of showing this is true?]

We have that $a_k$ < $2^k$, which is what we wanted to show.

Generally with my induction proofs I always get the inequality in some form such that it is evident to see that it is less than what we want to show or "substitute" into the inequality (ie: if a > b and b > c then a > c). Sometimes this involves a smaller remark on the side that I attempt to build an inequality to show this is true).

How can I show these sorts of steps better? It's even more tricky with polynomials and such.

Comment: Is using induction mandatory?

Comment: Yep. They are exercises in complete induction.

Comment: You have to be allowed *some* axioms and definitions. $2^k(7/8) < 2^k$ because $7/8 < 1$ and $2^k > 0$ so $2^k(7/8) < 2^k*1 = 2^k$.  That's it.  $a > b$ and $b > c$ then $a > c$ because order is transitive.  That's it.

Comment: Your proof is fine and you've shown everything that it can be reasonably expected for you to show.

Comment: you're proof looks fine, what may be annoying you is that an upper bound of 2^n isn't a particularly spectacular result about the sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are worried about three things.

1) If $a' < a$ and $b' < b$ and $c' < c$ can we say $a' + b' + c' < a + b + c$

The answer is yes.  If $x < y$ then $x + a < y + a$ is a basic axiom of order so

$a' < a \implies a' + b' < a  + b'$

$b' < b \implies a + b' < a + b$

And $c' < c \implies a' + b' + c' < a + b' + c' < a + b + c' < a + b + c$.

which brings up issue two

2) If $a < b$ and $b < c$ can we say $a < c$.

The answer is yes.  Order is defined/axiomatically assumed to be transitive.  This *is* a given-- for this exercise or in *any* context where order is presumed.

3) if $a < b$ then is $xa < xb$ (e.g. if $7/8 < 1$ so is $2^k(7/8) < 2^k *1$?)

The answer is **CONDITIONALLY** yes.  If $x> 0$ and $a<b$ then $xa < xb$.  This is a given axiom of ordered fields (or which the real numbers are one).  This is a given.

If, however $x = 0$ then $0a = 0 = 0b$ of course and if $x < 0$ then $(-x)a < (-x)b$ so $(-x) a + (x)b < 0$ (see 1) and $xb < xa$.  So if $x < 0$ then $xb < xa$.  This is a basic proposition (not an axiom but easily proven).  For this exercise you can take it as a given.

====

In some classes you will be given a formal and abstract definition of "<" and a formal and abstract definition of an "ordered field" of with the real numbers are *one* example and given some basic definitions and axioms and you will be asked to prove very basic propositions.  (For example that if $x<y$ then $-y < -x$  or $1/y < 1/x$ or that $x^2 \ge 0$ and so on.)

But for now, we can simply take these all as given.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!